# Criar spinner com valores dinamicos

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando criar um *spinner* com valores dinâmicos.

Está dando um erro quando tento setar o *adapter* no *spinner*, segue abaixo o erro e meu código.

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a
> null object reference
> ```

**Click:**

```
Sqlite sqlite = new Sqlite(getApplicationContext());
            final ArrayList<Ocorrencia> arrayList = sqlite.getListaOcorrencia();
            sqlite.close();

            final Spinner spnocorrencia = view.findViewById(R.id.spnocorrencia);
            OcorrenciaAdapter ocoAdapter = new OcorrenciaAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);

            Log.i("getItem", String.valueOf(ocoAdapter.getItem(1)));
            spnocorrencia.setAdapter(ocoAdapter); // erro está nessa linha
```

**Adapter:**

```
Context context;
ArrayList<Ocorrencia> arrayList;

public OcorrenciaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Ocorrencia> arrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}
```

A mensagem de erro diz que estou tentando setar um valor nulo no adapter, mas meu adapter retorna valor, em "`getCount()`", e também em "`getItemId()`".

Comment: `view.findViewById(R.id.spnocorrencia)` realmente existe na `view`?

Comment: Sim, existe.  <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/spnocorrencia"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"

                android:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:background="#15444947" />

Comment: Quando eu dou um Log.i pra ver o Count do adapter, ele retorna a quantidade correta que era para vir. Não sei se é algum problema nos valores, da maneira que foi salvo.

Comment: O problema acontece pois `spnocorrencia` está nula.

Comment: o problema pode estar aqui  "final Spinner spnocorrencia = view.findViewById(R.id.spnocorrencia);" ?

Comment: Sim. Adiciona `if (spnocorrencia == null) { Log.w("TAG", "Variável nula"); }` após `final Spinner spnocorrencia…` .

Comment: Realmente está nulo, eu só nao sei o motivo de estar. Pois eu criei o meu snipper na minha view, passei o id certinho, etc.

Comment: Defina um `id` no elemento `root` de sua `View` e depois utilize `Log.w("ViewId: ".concat(view.getId()))`, assim você se certificará se a `view` é a correta.

Comment: Elemento root, seria logo no começo da minha view? Estou começando agora com dev android, por isso varias duvidas.

Comment: Isso. O primeiro elemento do seu XML (`LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`, `ConstraintLayout` etc)

Comment: Amigo, deu certo aqui. Na parte "view.findViewById(R.id.spnocorrencia)", eu substitui por "dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spnocorrencia)"

Comment: É isso aí. Se possível posta o — como resposta — o problema e qual a solução. Inclusive você poderá marcar como resolvida.

Comment: Pois eu tinha chamado a minha view principal dessa maneira aqui "final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_product ,null);", a variavel "view", representava outra view do emu codigo

Comment: beleza, obrigado ai pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido!

O problema estava na linha `final Spinner spnocorrencia = view.findViewById(R.id.spnocorrencia);`

A variável *view* não representava a *view* que o meu *spinner* estava criado.

A criação da minha *view* correta está assim, `final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_product ,null);`.

Logo eu substitui a linha com erro e deixei dessa maneira abaixo:

```
final Spinner spnocorrencia = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spnocorrencia);
```

Troquei a variável *view*, por *dialogView*.